# RecyclerView doesn't have data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use rretrofit library to get data from server. Try for Log, data successful giving for me.But in `RecyclerView` I don't have any data. Inside `videoview` I see only a black figure and both `txtview` are empty. How I can transfer this data to recyclerview?
My fragment with response:

```
public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";
    public List<Video> videos;
    RecyclerView recList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, container, false);
        recList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        try {
            getVideos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void getVideos() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);
        Call<Videos> call = videoApi.getFeaturedVideo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Videos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Videos> call, Response<Videos> response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.body().videos.get(1).getTitle());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.body().videos.get(1).getScore());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.body().videos.get(1).getClipUrl());
                videos = response.body().videos;
                recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(videos);


                recList.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Videos> call, Throwable t) {

            }


        });
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {
    List<Video> call;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Video> call){
        this.call = call;

    }
    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row,parent,false);
        VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder = new VideoViewHolder(v);
        return videoViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String video_url = call.get(position).getClipUrl();
holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_url));

        holder.video_name.setText(call.get(position).getTitle());
      //  holder.video_like.setText(call.get(position).getScore());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return call.size();
    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardView;
        VideoView videoView;
        TextView video_name;
        TextView video_like;
        public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            videoView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            video_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Videoname_textView);
            video_like = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_textview);
        }
    }
}
```

card_view_row.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
<RelativeLayout

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
<VideoView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    />
    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Videoname_textView"
        android:text="NameofVideo"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoview"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/like_textview"
        android:text="Likes"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/videoview"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoview"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your list is has items but items is not show its contents? So, please check items view. If your list has no item, check your Adapter constructor or log itemcount

Comment: I checked items with logs in Fragment in onResonse method,and in that place I have data,but when I put it to adapter,maybe I send it in wrong way,because I havent data in RecyclerView.